# How to safely reuse the same object variable in a Viewmodel (working on a simple timer app)?

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture

I am working on a self devised coding problem in Android where I'm building a simple timer app that allows a user to count down a certain amount of time.

I have one activity that shows the timer `MainActivity` (the timer can also be started from this activity) and one activity that allows the user to select a countdown time and submit it (`SelectActivity`).

I use a `ViewModel` that holds a customized `CountDownTimer` class. A user can at any time go back to the `SelectActivity` and submit a new time. In my code I explicitly set the timer to `null` as you can see below (not the best code but I hope the idea comes across). I added `model.timer = null` afterwards.

The problem: If a user submits a new time, the `MainActivity` now shows 2 counters counting down in rapid succession (the remaining time is shown in one View).

My assumption was that by setting the timer to null I would get rid of the old timer. Is this assumption wrong? Am I approaching this problem entirely wrong?

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            model.timer = null
            model.timer = MyTimer(data?.getLongExtra("Message",11) ?: 0, 10, true).apply {
                setListener(model.timerListener)
            }
            model.timerStatus.value = StateTimer.INITIALIZED
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share how are you passing the data to your views?
Also, seems that you have another variable for this task

```
model.timerStatus.value = StateTimer.INITIALIZED
```

I guess this other line is affecting the way you show the information since you are initializing again the same instance.